# The ugliness of logging - Python example

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

So I'm working on a project which has some logging set up. We have designed the logging in a way so that if an exception happens, all the information at that point is logged. This is different to some traditional approaches where things are logged regardless of outcome along the way. I have coded the below example to simply explain the pattern we are using. In a nutshell, there is a global dictionary created which is used to store information as the programme runs. This dictionary is cleared and initialized at various points in the programme(something I don't like but is an "unnecessary evil"). The dictionary needs to be cleared as the looping operations only update some pieces of information. Anyway, enough jibber jabber below is the example:

```
import logging
import sys
import logmatic

l = logging.getLogger(__name__)
l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
sh = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
sh.setFormatter(logmatic.JsonFormatter())
l.addHandler(sh)

logging_dict = {}


def some_method(default_logging):
    some_loopable_data_structure = [1, 2, 3]
    for loop in some_loopable_data_structure:
        default_logging.clear()
        logging_dict.update(default_logging)
        logging_dict.update({'loop_count': loop})
        if loop == 2:
            logging_dict.update({'some_condition_triggered': 'stores a value which we need to clear each loop'})
        l.info('current logged message, loop {}'.format(loop), extra=logging_dict)


def main():
    default_logging = {'first_var': 'some initial var', 'second_var': 'another initial var'}

    some_method(default_logging)


main()
```

example output:

```
{
  "asctime" : "2018-02-06T13:47:38ZE. Australia Standard Time",
   "name" : "__main__",
   "processName" : "MainProcess",
   "filename" : "ugly_logging.py",
   "funcName" : "some_method",
   "levelname" : "INFO",
   "lineno" : 20,
   "module" : "ugly_logging",
   "threadName" : "MainThread",
   "message" : "current logged message, loop 3",
   "loop_count" : 3,
   "timestamp" : "2018-02-06T13:47:38ZE. Australia Standard Time"
}
```

and the same output if I remove

```
default_logging.clear()
```

output(contains logging from loop 2 & this is incorrect):

```
{
   "asctime" : "2018-02-06T13:58:50ZE. Australia Standard Time",
   "name" : "__main__",
   "processName" : "MainProcess",
   "filename" : "ugly_logging.py",
   "funcName" : "some_method",
   "levelname" : "INFO",
   "lineno" : 22,
   "module" : "ugly_logging",
   "threadName" : "MainThread",
   "message" : "current logged message, loop 3",
   "some_condition_triggered" : "stores a value which we need to clear each loop",
   "second_var" : "another initial var",
   "first_var" : "some initial var",
   "loop_count" : 3,
   "timestamp" : "2018-02-06T13:58:50ZE. Australia Standard Time"
}
```

in this small example, the solution doesn't seem to bad. As the python module has grown in size and complexity I am now passing around "default logging" dicts to various methods to initialize the logging at certain places where I clear it & it's all starting to look messy. Things I don't like about this approach

- passing dict around to all methods with "default logging" information
- having to clear the dictionary every time I loop
- the above seems error-prone and doesn't scale well

does anyone have any suggestions on a better approach that still sticks to our logging philosophy of "only logging relevant information at certain points" as opposed to the "log everything" traditional approach?